# Is there a way to automatically test whether there are any designer errors in winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms

Is there a way to force the designer engine to run from a unit test for a given designable WinForms control (ie, one with an autogenerated designer.cs file)? It would be nice to automatically capture any errors that would prevent the Visual Studio designer view from opening for the control.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by `designer errors`?

Comment: anything that would cause designer error screen to come up

Comment: I understand the question just fine, but I don't know an answer. He's probably dynamically creating a WinForm file, and wants to make sure there are no errors in the FormName.Designer.vb file.

Comment: @HardCode `He's probably......` Maybe you are right(BTW question is tagged as c# not VB) but I don't like to *guess* the question and answer it depending on my *assumptions*

Comment: I don't think there's any requisite to how his designer files are being geenrated.  Given a winforms control, is the visual studio designer going to be able to open it. This question seems straight forward to me.

Comment: @moderator Explain your reason for deleting the comments.

Answer (score -3):

Essentially, the designer is calling `InitializeComponent` on your `Form` to display it. There may be a few differences, but nothing too significant.

Because `InitializeComponent` is by default private, the equivalent would be to create a new `Form`, as the default constructor calls `InitializeComponent`.

So just doing

```
new Form1();
```

is enough to ensure `InitializeComponent` doesn't throw any exceptions.

Comment: This isn't quite what I'm looking for. Quite often, the designer won't load for a control, but the control works just fine in my program in debug mode (meaning the InitializeComponent() code is working just fine).

Comment: What code I need to run from my test is the code that the designer uses to reflectively inspect the InitializeComponent() code (along with other parts of my code it may also happen to look at) to get the infomation it needs to build the the designer environment for that control.

Comment: I doubt you have access to that code, as it is part of Visual Studio. I should also mention, I think if you add a message box in `InitializeComponent`, it will be displayed by the designer, meaning that it is being called, and not just examined.

Comment: Its true, the designer does call some of my own code. Sometimes it starts calling code deep into my database access libraries, causing designer errors.

Comment: I have a team of several people on this project, the point of all this is to fail a test on them if they forget use a bunch of the tricks we've discovered to prevent some of these designer errors. Its no fun opening a designer weeks later and discovering it had been broken for awhile.

Comment: Design-time checks (like Control.DesignMode) cause different program flow when loaded in the designer, so this is not sufficient. There are also inheritance scenarios that break the designer and only the designer.